# openapi-generator generator to do reverse

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I have the yaml file and also an existing pom.xml file with all the config settings. How can I do the reverse and generate the API using the yaml file and existing pom.xml file? It this possible?